# Ensure that nested fields where the path is defined by a variable trigger React.useMemo update when added to the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-usememo

I use TypeScript 4 and React 17

I had this code in a custom hook:

```
  const myValue = useMemo((): string[] => {
    if (someCondition) {
      return (myMap?.field && myMap.field.[subfieldId]) || null
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }, [myMap.field.[subfieldId]])
```

ESlint complained that myMap.field.[subfieldId] had to be moved in a variable to be checked progammatically.

So I changed to this:

```
  const currentData: string[] | null = (myMap?.field && myMap.field.[subfieldId]) || null

  const myValue = useMemo((): string[] => {
    if (someCondition) {
      return currentData
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }, [currentData])
```

I'm not sure that letting the variable in the upper scope, being recalculated at each rendering is a good practice, I'm even worried that an infinite loop could be created.

ESLInt suggest me to to this instead, that is much more simple:

```
  const myValue = useMemo((): string[] => {
    if (someCondition) {
      return (myMap?.field && myMap.field.[subfieldId]) || null
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }, [myMap.field])
```

Will myMap.field be enought for React to find out that myMap.field[subfieldId] change? I guess it shall be. Indeed, React will not know what changed if I only put myMap, because the object reference itself does not change, but when comparing the previous and the new myMap.field, React check all the sub-fields. Does it?

Comment: No, react doesn't compare properties, it only does a reference comparison on the main object. If you could elaborate on what your code actually does it would be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. I need to conditionally return the value contained in the field myMap.field.[subfieldId] or another value from another similar subfieldId2 field. I don't know by advance the subfiledsIds, these are parameters of the custom hook.

Answer (score 1):

According the react hook linter:

> React Hook React.useMemo has an unnecessary dependency: 'myMap'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'myMap' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

So you should be fine with this:

```js
const myValue = useMemo((): string[] => {
  if (someCondition) {
    return myMap?.field[subfieldId] || null
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}, [subfieldId]);
```